# the parametrization of a Gumbel in terms of a Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics, extreme-value-analysis

Extreme Value Distribution From a Gaussian. I was wondering how the parametrization of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of a Gumbel $e^{-e^{-\frac{x-\alpha }{\beta }}}$ was done in terms of a cumulative Gaussian $F(x)^n$ (where $n$ is the number of observations) and inverse cumulative error functions, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $-\sqrt{2} \text{ erfc}^{-1}\left(2-\frac{2}{n}\right)$ and $\sqrt{2}
   \left(\text{erfc}^{-1}\left(2-\frac{2}{n}\right)-\text{erfc}^{-1}\left(2-\frac{2}{e   n}\right)\right)$ respectively.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does not [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105749/264124) answer suffice?